# Odoo domain is not working with new records

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-12

I have a tree view for **account.analytic.line** model and fields *date, description, project and task*.

This is from **Project module**.

What I want to make is to filter project and tasks fields. I've made some configuration in **res.config.settings** model, to set and get the task stages and project stages.

```
class TimesheetSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

    task_stages = fields.Many2many('project.task.type')
    project_stages = fields.Many2many('project.status')

    def set_values(self):
        res = super(TimesheetSettings, self).set_values()
        settings = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
        settings.set_param('hr_timesheet.task_stages', self.task_stages.ids)
        settings.set_param('hr_timesheet.project_stages', self.project_stages.ids)
        return res

    @api.model
    def get_values(self):
        res = super(TimesheetSettings, self).get_values()
        settings = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
        task_stages = settings.get_param('hr_timesheet.task_stages')
        project_stages = settings.get_param('hr_timesheet.project_stages')
        
        res.update(task_stages=[(6, 0, literal_eval(task_stages))] if task_stages else False,
            project_stages=[(6, 0, literal_eval(project_stages))] if project_stages else False)
        return res
```

So then, I inherited **account.analytic.line** and put two new fields: *task_stages_domain* and *allowed_tasks*. Both computed, and the computed function will take the params from **res.config.settings**.

I've created an array to save the tasks stages configurated in settings and search the tasks stages with those ids. And then I've created a second array to save the project stages configurated in settings and search the project stages with those ids.

After that, I looped through the records and I set the field project_stages_domain with the project founded previously. Then, if the field project_id is set, I'll search the tasks corresponding with the same project_id and stage_id in the previously founded tasks stages.

```
class AccountAnalyticLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.analytic.line'

    project_stages_domain = fields.Many2many('project.status', compute='_get_allowed_stages')
    allowed_tasks = fields.Many2many('project.task', compute='_get_allowed_stages')

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('date', 'project_id')
    def _get_allowed_stages(self):
        settings = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
        task_stages = settings.get_param('hr_timesheet.task_stages')
        project_stages = settings.get_param('hr_timesheet.project_stages')

        arr = []
        if task_stages:
            for num in task_stages:
                if num.isdigit():
                    arr.append(int(num))

        stages = self.env['project.task.type'].search([('id', 'in', arr)])

        arr2 = []
        if project_stages:
            for num in project_stages:
                if num.isdigit():
                    arr2.append(int(num))

        stages_project = self.env['project.status'].search([('id', 'in', arr2)])

        for rec in self:
            rec.project_stages_domain = stages_project
            if rec.project_id:
                tasks = self.env['project.task'].search([('stage_id', 'in', stages.ids), ('project_id', '=', rec.project_id.id)])
                rec.allowed_tasks = tasks
```

Problem is, the domain for task is not working when I want to create a new record, but if I want to edit an existing record, it works. The XML is defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="hr_timesheet_line_tree_inherit_task_project_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.analytic.line.tree.hr_timesheet.inherit.task_project_filter</field>
        <field name="model">account.analytic.line</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="5"/>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_timesheet.hr_timesheet_line_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='project_id']" position="replace">
                <field name="project_id" required="1" domain="[('project_status', 'in', project_stages_domain)]"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='task_id']" position="replace">
                <field name="task_id" context="{'default_project_id': project_id}" domain="[('id', 'in', allowed_tasks)]"/>
                <field name="project_stages_domain" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="allowed_tasks" invisible="1"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```